# Faking fence post corner

Tags: fence, post

I have an issue with a street light wire weaving in and out of my property line. I was able to dig one hole about as safely as I could near the front of the house. I need to bring it up a little further but then it will lead into the wire coming in on an angle. I am already working around this wire and sitting in almost 2ft into my property. If I put another post at angle, and instead of putting the fence panel on angle, build it out to 90 degree as normal and put a stabilizer post maybe either on top of a few inches of tamped gravel, or on top of a deck concrete block buried into the ground a little. OR just sit it into the dirt tamped a little and do nothing else with it other than use it to keep the fence from sagging in that little area, if that would even be a problem. The distance would probably be 3ft to the other angled post.

Same thing for the utility boxes in the back. I was going to box around them to keep them outside but there are so many wires and that stupid street light wire comes in on an angle there.. So if I fake the corner post on that one too.. I figure the load from the wind would push on to the connecting posts.. I have drawn pictures to show an example..

[image: Picture of issue]

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried contacting whoever owns the light fitting ?  Loosing 600mm of your property is bad enough.

Comment: Yea, it's the town they were the ones who came out and marked it. I ended up just paying a professional company to do it as I didn't want to risk hitting the line, and they came out and hand dug in those areas. They were able to make the fence straight from the back of the yard to the front, and only a couple inches from the property line. So for me it was worth the money to hire someone. The company has insurance to protect themselves if they hit the line, so they are willing to take the risk, where if I were to hit it, it could cost a couple thousand to have the city come repair.